# Solving $\sqrt3\;\cos(x)= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm currently stuck on this trigonometric equation:

$$\sqrt3 \;\cos(x)= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$$

Here's what I've tried so far (2 methods):

Method n.1
$$\sqrt3 \;\cos(x)= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$$
$$\sqrt3 \;(1-\sin^2x)= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$$
$$\sqrt3-\sqrt3\;\sin^2x= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$$
$$2\sqrt3-2\sqrt3\;\sin^2x- \sin\;x=0$$

$$// \; let\; \sin \;(x)=y \;//$$

$$2\sqrt3-2\sqrt3\;y^2- y=0$$
$$y=\frac {1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4(-2\sqrt3)(2\sqrt3)}}{2(-2\sqrt3)}$$
$$y=\frac {1\pm\sqrt{1^2(8\sqrt3)(2\sqrt3)}}{-4\sqrt3}$$
$$y=\frac {1\pm\sqrt{1^2+16\times3}}{-4\sqrt3}$$
$$y=\frac {1\pm\sqrt{49}}{-4\sqrt3}$$
$$y=\frac {1\pm7}{-4\sqrt3}$$

$$y_1=\frac {1+7}{-4\sqrt3}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt3}=\frac{-2\sqrt3}{3}$$
$$y_2=\frac {1-7}{-4\sqrt3}=\frac{-3}{-2\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

$$\arcsin(\frac{-2\sqrt3}{3})=\nexists$$
$$\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})=60°$$

$$x_1= 60°+360°k$$
$$x_1= 120°+360°k$$

Method n.2
$$\sqrt3 \;\cos(x)= \sin\;(\frac {x}{2})$$
$$\sqrt3 \; \cos(x)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{ 1-cos (x)}}{2}$$

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance! :D

Comment: $\cos x \neq 1-\sin^2 x$.  You need a square root.

Comment: Please use $\cos x = 1 - 2 \sin^2 (\frac {x}{2})$

Comment: Solving the quadratic, you get $t = \sin (\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}, - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: In the first method, you appear to have multiplied by 2 to convert $\sin\frac{x}{2}$ to $\sin x$.

Comment: For the half-angle formula, remember, the 2 goes *inside* the radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with $\sqrt{3}\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{x}{2})$. We can start by using our half-angle formula to replace $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$ with $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}}$. Making the substitution and squaring both sides, we now see that $3\cos^2 (x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}$. Multiplying both sides by $2$, we get $6\cos^2(x)=1-\cos(x)$, and rearranging the equation, we get $6\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$.

Now we can say that $y=\cos(x)$. This turns the equation into $6y^2+y-1=0$. This is an elementary quadratic equation, the solution of which is $y=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4(6)(-1)}}{2(6)}=\frac{-1\pm5}{12}$, or $y=\frac{1}{3}$ and $y=\frac{-1}{2}$.

If $y=\cos(x)$, then of course, $x=\arccos(y)$. And so, $x=\arccos(\frac{1}{3})\approx1.231$ and $x=\arccos(\frac{-1}{2})=\frac{-2\pi}{3}$.

One thing briefly to note is that there's a small amount of strangeness here due to the fact that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$. Specifically, a calculator will tell you that $\arccos(\frac{-1}{2})=\frac{2\pi}{3}$, which is true, but does not satisfy our given equation: $\sqrt{3}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. In order to remedy this, we switch the sign from positive to negative, keeping the value of the cosine expression negative while switching the sine expression's value to also be negative.

Comment: Thank you! This was a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If we make the substitution$$x=\pi+2y$$

the equation becomes
$$-\sqrt{3}\cos(2y)=\cos(y)=\sqrt{3}(1-2\cos^2(y))$$
or
$$2\sqrt{3}\cos^2(y)+\cos(y)-\sqrt{3}=0$$
with
$$\Delta=25$$